# DIY protection board for lithium-ion batteries. How to scale a schematic?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, diy, bms

I need to build a DIY protection board for a university project. We are not allowed to buy one online so I have to construct it myself.

I have found a variety of schematics accomplishing the same thing, however, I do not know how to scale one up to use for my purpose. Most of them are for 3-4S configurations, on the other hand, mine is 18S6P with 72V-100A ratings.

Is there any way to make this thing work for my aim?

[image: 4S30A Protection Board Schematic]

DW01A and HY2213 are pretty simple to understand and they do not require further adjustments for my configuration. I can only assume that the power MOSFETs are the issue here.

My goal is to duplicate the DW01A and HY2213 parts 18 times and change the MOSFETs for 100A rating. Is this something I can do or am I just tricking myself?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Requirement is clear enough.

Comment: You could try building it with 100 V FET's. Execute your testplan to see if it meets all the specifications. You do have a test plan for your BMS, right? But it is just about the most minimal BMS possible. Usually 18S BMS's have a few more features.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like someone has to answer. I assume you understand the circuitry:

1. The bottom DW01A detects the voltage drop on R004||R004, that is current sensing resistors.
2. Each DW01 detects OC and OD, sends signal down the string of 1Mohm-s to cut off the switching FETs.
3. HY2123 turns on the bleeding resistors at a set voltage.

> Is there any way to make this thing work for my aim?

Yes, as you said, calculate the voltage and current and adjust the parts. You can make 18S6P in a single group, or combine multiple of small groups in series and parallel.

---

However, though you did not invite any other answers,  I have to advise, from my experience in designing BMS; I wouldn't feel safe to see any battery packs around with this circuitry, especially for 18S6P Lion battery pack carrying 7200W instant power.

1. If 18S goes in a group, the control signal from the top goes down 18Mohm resistor, 18 of 1Mohm cascaded, relying on the cells down the string. It will be sensitive to any noise.
2. Too many parts are on the critical path, that can bring failure rate high, and any failures are crucial.
3. There is no error detection except OC & OD, no warning, no diagnostics.
4. Multiple point failure can not be detected.
5. Balancing circuitrys become shunt voltage regulators, if it does any good, limits the battery capacity, wastes charge against the effort to reduce current consumption using high impedance signal paths.

The worst concern is safety. Sorry to say this, but it would feel like a time-bomb.

Comment: Would you be kind enough to explain the purpose of the 510k resistors, the transistors connected to the 510k resistors and string of 1Mohm-s?

Comment: @swichztra DW01A drives PNP TR-s through 510k, when the OC/OD pin is low. Base drive current is about Ib = (Vbat - Vbe) / 510k = 3 / 510k => 6uA. That current, in turn, drives the NPN TR (3904) base through 1Meg ohm string, (Vbat - Vce) / 1Meg => 3.2uA. Eventually, the 1Meg ohm on the NPN collector (& FET gate) is driven, switches the FET-s.

Comment: What is the purpose of those 10M resistors sir?

Comment: @swichztra I do not know. Since the circuit components are such a high impedance, they might need to compensate/bleed leakage and parasitic with 10M & 0.47uF.

Comment: I see, I re-did your calculations again:
Ib = Vcc - Veb(on) / Rb = 3.7-0.65/510k = 5.7uA 
and
Ic = Vcc-Vec(sat)/Rc = 3.7-0.25V /1x10^6 = 3.4uA, so the question is how would these calculations be affected if OC/OD pins were high. What are the output of the OC/OD pins if they are high and the associated calculations with them. Because I understand that the PNP transistors are driven when the pins are low but what about when they are high?

Comment: FET-s turn on, since gates are biased by 1 Meg to B3.

Comment: So when the pins are low --> the PNP transistors drive PNP transistors and they drive the MOSFETs. When the pins are high --> the base emitter voltage of the PNP transistor is zero and no current will flow on the collector thus the pullup resistor shut downs the associated MOSFETs. Am I right?

Comment: @swichztra It sounds confusing, did I make mistake (?). OC/OD low => PNP on => NPN on => FET off........... OC/OD high => PNP off => NPN off => FET on. Ha! this sounds better :)

Comment: Ah I understand now, thanks a lot for you help!

Comment: @swichztra You are welcome! Thanks, we've just finished before we get moved to the chat room.